# Accessing Event details not possible anymore (Frontend)

Tags: civievent, api, joomla

Joomla 3.8.2 and CiviCRM 4.7.27

I got recently some user reply's that the event details con not be accessed anymore, thus no event regi, stration is possible.The event list is visible in the frontend, but clicking the "Event Name" or "read more" results in:

CiviCRM-001
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
API permission check failed for Event/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM and access CiviEvent and view event info

This error may be related to an update, however I can not determine which one as the feedback was not immediate. I checked the access rights for civiEvent listing and registration, they are still set to public, nothing changed there.

May be a bug... Anybody who has a suggestion where to start?

Currently I cant find the error report ... sorry

### Thanks for your input

Joomla shows in debug mode:
Call stack

## Function    Location

1   ()  JROOT/libraries/legacy/error/error.php:200
2   JError::raise()     JROOT/libraries/legacy/error/error.php:277
3   JError::raiseError()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php:468
4   CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:55
5   CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()   JROOT/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:96
6   civicrm_invoke()    JROOT/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:11
7   require_once()  JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:381
8   Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent()    JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:356
9   Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent()     JROOT/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:194
10  Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->dispatch()  JROOT/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:233
11  Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute()     JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:267
12  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT/index.php:49

Comment: Found this:[Thu Nov 09 13:21:16 2017] [error] [client 79.239.xxx.xxx] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /etc/apache2/confixx_phpini/web139/7/php.ini on line 1969, referer: http://samadhi-institute.org/index.php/de/veranstaltungen-seminare/naechste-veranstaltungen

Comment: As this is a hosted server I have no access to php.ini

Comment: Beim debug mode erhalte ich von joomla:

Answer (score 1):

In  CiviCRM Configuration, Access rights: CiviCRM: access CiviCRM  was set to "inherited" needet to be "allowed". Now it works!